Why the heck does Windows 11 keep removing new text document from context menu?
A couple months ago, Windows 11 randomly removed "Text Document" from the "new" menu in the explorer context menu. I had to go out of my way and modify the registry to get it back. Now it has randomly disappeared again. This is literally the ONLY type of file I create from the context menu. I probably use it at least a few dozen times a day. I have NEVER IN MY LIFE ever created a new Office document from this menu, which are the only options present now. This is INFURIATING.

I would guess this is a bug with your computer. I have not seen that issue happening with any other W11 computer, and I run several of various sorts, all fully updated. As you state elsewhere you have not installed new software recently, that pretty much leaves "bug" as the cause. I would try Windows repair installs as your next step to resolve. If you can identify WHEN it disappears, you may be able to determine a trigger and then address that, but that would take some effort on your part.

A workaround, since I do not know what would cause that New menu item to be lost. and have never experienced that issue, is to make it trivial to restore with a Registry (.reg) file.


Press Windows, type reged, select Regedit and press Enter to run Regedit.
Navigate to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt (or paste that into location bar).
Right-click key .txt, select Export, and save as a .reg file with a memorable name.
Next time Windows 11 loses that context menu item, double-click the .reg file to restore it.

You might also want to use a third-party utility, such as Nirsoft's ShellMenuNew, to make it easier and safer to modify that context menu.

Such tools can make it easier to find the Registry location of New context items.
You state, "This is literally the ONLY type of file I create from the context menu." Right-click an entry and select Disable to hide New MS Office entries. The disabled items can be restored just as easily, if needed.
As for cause of the issue, I'd look to any new software installations, software updates, and Microsoft Windows Updates as possible culprits.

The infuriating bit is simply that it makes no sense. I haven't installed any software in ages. It seems like Windows updates are doing this.

@Chris_F, Is this a Win 11 bug? PC's here that have not gone over to Linux are still on Win 10, and I've never experienced that issue in 10.
